# Why does Volley retry on 401 and 403?

Tags: android, android-volley

So, the Android network library [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley) retries requests when status code is either 401 or 403. See below code snippet from [`BasicNetwork`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java) class.

```
    ...
    networkResponse = new NetworkResponse(statusCode, responseContents, responseHeaders, false, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - requestStart);
    if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED || // which is 401
        statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN) {    // which is 403
        attemptRetryOnException("auth", request, new AuthFailureError(networkResponse));
    } else if (statusCode >= 400 && statusCode <= 499) {
        // Don't retry other client errors.
        throw new ClientError(networkResponse);
    } else if {
    ...
```

But why?

First of all, I looked up its commit history, but found no explanation on this issue. Retrying on 401 and 403 was present from the very first commit, and hasn't been changed since then.

Also I looked up rfc spec, and the [rfc2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) spec says, "**the request SHOULD NOT be repeated**" on 403, 
and "**The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field**" on 401. But current volley implementation just retries without any refreshing or fixing the problem. For example, [Google Analytics API documentaion](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors) recommends that clients should "not retry without fixing the problem" on 401 and 403.

Also I found someone ranted ["Volley must not retry on HTTP 401 and 403"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/volley-users/LbaEhNuxK5w), but it seems no further discussion took place.

Am I missing something? Can someone share some background thoughts on this retry policy?

Comment: `Am I missing something?`  Other than the fact that most developers of HTTP client type software are, bluntly, entirely ignorant of the RFCs -- when they're not intentionally disregarding them?  No, you're not missing anything.

Comment: This caused huge server traffic in my case since it creates an endless retry loop...